# Saving a document returned from "Open in" IOS

Tags: ios

I have activated the "Open in" feature for my app so that users can open their docs in my app. The app appears under the open in list, and when the user presses the icon, my app opens. The problem is that I can't seem to understand how to then go on saving the file. This is what I learned from the numerous StackOverflow questions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if ([[DBChooser defaultChooser] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
        }
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

I am trying to catch the data in the following way, but there is an error. Furthermore I was wondering if this method will cause any interference with my already existing Dropbox importer... I have read that the files are automatically saved in the documents/Inbox path.

As file types I can open I set public.content (all the files the Documents interaction controller can open, I believe).

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: The one of NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

Comment: But what is the actual error displayed in the log from that??

Comment: nothing, only that...

Comment: Oh right. Open-in doesn't seem to work with logging sometimes. Maybe try debugging with a break point so you can hover over and or print out the value of the error?

Comment: Logging the url gives a path to the file beginning with /// and file private

Comment: Do you knowhow to use breakpoints? You can setup the app to start debugging once it's been opened. Set a break point at the NSLog line, and then hit run/debug. It will build and wait for the app to open on your device. Then you start up the app by sending it the file from another app and it will start and then stop at the breakpoint. There, hover over the error and/or type "po error.localizedDescription" in the debugger window to get the actual error.

Comment: I think it's more elegant to save the URL in your app and open the file immediately with the application of the user's choice. If the file is very big, it will take a long time until the user can proceed to the next step. You can resume downloading the file when the user comes back to your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{

 if(url !=nil)
{
  NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  [urlData writeToFile:YourDocumentsDirectoryPath atomically:YES];
 }
  return YES;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Following Code :

```
#define DocumentsDirectory [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
     NSLog(@"URL : %@", url);

     NSArray *tempArray = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
     NSString *aStrPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",DocumentsDirectory, [tempArray lastObject]];

     NSData *aData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     [aData writeToFile:aStrPath atomically:YES];

     return YES;
}
```

This Code is working...!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my open in code that works. should be noted that these are pdf's, and it is possible that the problem is with the type of file you are opening. 
Also note that it is important to clean out the inbox file if you are copying the files locally. Otherwise you are double saving the data and using up space.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    if ([url isFileURL])

  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:inboxPath];
    [data writeToFile:scorePath atomically:YES];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:inboxPath error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

when you finish opening the document,the document gets saved to your app directory.The thing is you have to fetch the url and do necessary operations.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    // your code  

    return YES;
}
```

use this delegate method in the Appdelegate.m.this method is called ,when you open any document in your app.

Download iExplorer,using which you can see through the documents and files in your application.After opening file using `open-in feature`,your app's document directory gets updated.